# Reform a postgreSQL query using one (or more) index - Example

Tags: postgresql

I am a beginner in PostgreSQL and, after understanding very basic things, I want to find out how I can get a better performance (on a query) by using an index (one or more).                                                                          I have read some documentation, but I would like a specific example so as to "catch" it.

MY EXAMPLE: Let's say I have just a table (MyTable) with three columns (Customer(text), Time(timestamp), Consumption(integer)) and I want to find the customer(s) with the maximum consumption on '2014-07-01 01:00:00'.                                                          MY SOLUTION (without index usage):

```
SELECT Customer FROM MyTable WHERE Time='2013-07-01 02:00:00' 
AND Consumption=(SELECT MAX(consumption) FROM MyTable);
```

----> What would be the exact full code, using - at least one - index for the              query-example above ?

Answer (score 0):

The correct query (using a correlated subquery) would be:

```
SELECT Customer
FROM MyTable
WHERE Time = '2013-07-01 02:00:00' AND
      Consumption = (SELECT MAX(t2.consumption) FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t2.Time = '2013-07-01 02:00:00');
```

The above is very reasonable.  An alternative approach if you want exactly one row returned is:

```
SELECT Customer
FROM MyTable
WHERE Time = '2013-07-01 02:00:00'
ORDER BY Consumption DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

And the best index is `MyTable(Time, Consumption, Customer)`.

Comment: * You mean that the right full code would  be to write - first - the CREATE statement of this index and - after that - the exact same code "SELECT ... "          ?      Just this ?

Comment: ** If it is just this, is it possible to be no difference between the execution plan of the 1st case (without index) and the execution plan of the 2nd case (with index) ?    (noticed so by using the EXPLAIN command)

Comment: @Emma . . . The optimizer takes many things into account when determining the execution plan.  On a small table, for instance, it may choose not to use an index.   The first version should also work very well with the specified index.

Comment: Hmm.. and let's say we want to create an index so as to improve the "find the AVG consumption for EVERY Customer" query: An appropriate index would be, considering that the leftmost column to be indexed is the most prioritized, the            MyTable(Customer,Consumption)  ?     Is this the same as creating / using two indices:             MyTable(Customer) and then, MyTable(Consumption)  ?

Comment: @Emma . . . The questions in your comment are more appropriate for a new question.